How to check expl3 function return value with \ifthenelse
I have written the expl3 function below to test if a input string fits to a predefined pattern.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_const:Nn \c__single_cable_regex {^(NYX|KNX|ETH)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}$}

\NewDocumentCommand \testCableNumberPattern {m}
{
    \regex_match:NnTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1}
    {true}
    {false}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\cableNumberOne{NYX-K001}
\def\cableNumberTwo{NYM-K001}

\expandafter\testCableNumberPattern\expanded{{\cableNumberOne}}% Returns: "true"

\ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\testCableNumberPattern\expanded{{\cableNumberOne}}}{true}}{
    CableNumber is defined!
}{
    CableNumber is not defined!
}

\testCableNumberPattern{\cableNumberTwo}% Returns: "false"

\ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\testCableNumberPattern\expanded{{\cableNumberTwo}}}{true}}{
    CableNumber is defined!
}{
    CableNumber is not defined!
}
\end{document}

As you can see, the function is working as expected, the pattern is correctly tested and the LateX3 function is returning the expected value.
But why is my \ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\testCableNumberPattern\expanded{{\cableNumberOne}}}{true}} statement not working?
I saw some solutions where a temp variable is set whithin the expl3 function and then in the Latex2 code, this variable is just tested. Something like this:
\regex_const:Nn \c__single_cable_regex {^(NYX|KNX|ETH)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}$}%
\regex_const:Nn \c__double_cable_regex {^(NYX)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}\ /\ (KNX)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}$}

\NewDocumentCommand \testCableNumberPattern {m}
{
    \regex_match:NnTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1}
    {\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\cableTestResult\expandafter{\true}}
    {
        \regex_match:NnTF \c__double_cable_regex {#1}
        {\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\cableTestResult\expandafter{\true}}
        {\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\cableTestResult\expandafter{\false}}
    }
}

But for me this is not the best option...
So is there a way to test the return value of a LaTeX3 function in LaTeX2?
EDIT in regards to the comments
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\regex_const:Nn \c__single_cable_regex {^(NYX|KNX|ETH)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}$}


\NewDocumentCommand \testCableNumberPattern {m} {
\regex_match:NnTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\cableNumberOne{NYX-K001}
\def\cableNumberTwo{NYM-K001}

\testCableNumberPattern{NYX-K001}{yes it matches}{no it doesnt match}

\testCableNumberPattern{NYM-K001}{yes it matches}{no it doesnt match}

\end{document}


In the comment there is the proposal to use \regex_match:NeTF this is not compiling at my end so I switched back to \regex_match:NnTF was this just a typo or did I miss something?
The new MWE is just working, when I put in the string itself e.g. NYX-K001 when I use \cableNumberOne it is still not working.
I would like to test a second pattern like this: \regex_const:Nn \c__double_cable_regex {^(NYX)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}\ /\ (KNX)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}$} How can I concatenate the two pattern? In my original example I did it like this:

Test two patterns:
\NewDocumentCommand \testCableNumberPattern {m}%
{
    \regex_match:NnTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1}
    {true}
    {
        \regex_match:NnTF \c__double_cable_regex {#1}
        {true}
        {false}
    }
}


Why are you using this with ifthen in the first place? expl3 is vastly more powerful and can do everything that ifthen does.

There are no reasonable use cases for mixing \ifthenelse and L3 code. There are not so many use cases for \ifthenelse at all although it's OK for simple tests. But L3 has far better conditionals available so if using that layer do not use ifthen at all.

you only need to load expl3 if you have a very old latex, these functions have been in the format for several years.

just define \NewDocumentCommand \testCableNumberPattern {m} {    \regex_match:NeTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1}}  then the argument will expand so no need for \expandafter .. \expanded  and you can use the true and false arguments directly, no need to test for true  for example\testCableNumberPattern{\cableNumberOne}{yes it matches}{no it doesnt match}

@DavidCarlisle I like your approach! But there are some open questions, which I have summarized in a new Edit. :)

\NewDocumentCommand \testCableNumberPattern {mmm}% {     \regex_match:NnTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1}     {#2}     {         \regex_match:NnTF \c__double_cable_regex {#1}         {#2}         {#3}     } }

@DavidCarlisle why did you use three input variables now? Maybe I explained it wrong. I just want to test if the input variable \cableNumberOne fits to the first or the second pattern. So it it fits to one of them use the TRUE path, if both are not matching use the FALSE path.

that's what it does. you have three arguments, the thing to test the true branch and the false branch, in the first version I could short cut as if \foo has two arguments, \def\new{\foo} is equivalent to \def\new#1#2{\foo{#1}{#2}}  but in the second version I needed the arguments explicitly (it should be the e version again though not n)

@DavidCarlisle Okay, first thing is clear and it works now for \testCableNumberPattern{NYX-K001}{yes}{no} But I'm still struggling with using \cableNumberOne instead of the raw string. When I try to use \regex_match:NeTF my compilation "never ends..." So I helped myself again with \expandafter\testCableNumberPattern\expandafter{\cableNumberOne}{yes}{no} but of course the use of e for expanding would create a much more readable code...

cleaned up (cc @DavidCarlisle)

Since David can't answer right now without jeopardising a palindrome.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% the $ are changed just because it screws up highlighting in vim for the rest of the file
\regex_const:Nn \c__single_cable_regex {^(NYX|KNX|ETH)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}\Z}
\regex_const:Nn \c__double_cable_regex {^(NYX)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}\ /\ (KNX)\-(K|E|O|D)\d{3}\Z}
% internal function belonging to module pascal
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pascal_cable_test:nnn
{
  \regex_match:NeTF \c__single_cable_regex {#1} {#2}
  {
    \regex_match:NeTF \c__double_cable_regex {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
}
% #1 is the thing to test
% #2 is what to do if it matches either regex
% #3 is what to do if it matches neither
\NewDocumentCommand  \testCableNumberPattern { m +m +m }
{
  \pascal_cable_test:nnn {#1} { #2 } { #3 }
}
% \regex_match:NeTF isn't defined by the kernel
% however, \regex_match:NnTF is defined, so we can generate \regex_match:NeTF
% the 'n' version is the 'base function'
% the 'e' version expands the second argument before passing it to the base function
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF { Ne }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\cableNumberOne{NYX-K001}
\def\cableNumberTwo{NYM-K001}
% test failure with a macro
\def\cableUnknown{XXX-YABC012za}

\testCableNumberPattern{NYX-K001}{yes it matches}{no it doesn't match}

\testCableNumberPattern{NYM-K001}{yes it matches}{no it doesn't match}

% test matching macros
\testCableNumberPattern{\cableNumberOne}{yes it matches}{no it doesn't match}

\testCableNumberPattern{\cableUnknown}{yes it matches}{no it doesn't match}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}



+1 : excellent reason for answering

@DavidCarlisle / cfr Thank you for unlimited support! It‘s great to see how competent you guys are supporting and having a lot of fun on top :)

@Pascal I don't think David plans to answer, so accept or not as you wish. (not saying you should accept - just withdrawing the request that you not do so.)

@cfr I just waited for your hint ;)
