How to store a variable that is set inside a double-nested foreachloop
To configure my LaTeX document, I use a multidimensional array where a lot of configuration parameters are stored.
Depending on external .csv input files, I have to parse through sub arrays and take the configuration parameters I need.
Sometimes I need to temporarily store some of these parameters. For this Use-Case I would like to find the best approach. I think my issue is somehow related to an expanding issue, but I can not find the complete root cause.
As you can see in my MWE, I have added two approaches. The first one is much more simple because I don't need any "helper function" but it is only working with the already expanded "raw string". When I switch from the raw string to the second foreach loop element \noexpand\elementB then it doesn't work anymore. I played a bit with using an additional \expanded keyword, but without success.
The second approach is working as expected and the variable is stored successfully. But of course this is probably not the smartest way to do it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcounter{counter}
\newcommand{\tempVariable}{}
\newcommand{\firstInnerElement}{value1}
\newcommand{\secondInnerElement}{value2}
\newcommand{\thirdInnerElement}{value3}

\def\innerArray{
    {\firstInnerElement},{\secondInnerElement},{\thirdInnerElement}
}

\def\outerArray{
    {\innerArray}
}

\newcommand{\storeVariable}[1]{
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\tempVariable\expandafter{#1}
}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{counter}{1}
    \foreach \elementA in \outerArray {
        \begingroup
        \edef\temp{\endgroup
            \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\elementB in \elementA {
            \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counter}}{2}}{
                    % Instead of "value 2", I would like to use "\noexpand\elementB"
                    %\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\tempVariable{value2}% First approach just works with a direct string
                    \noexpand\storeVariable{\noexpand\elementB}% Second approach works, but is very cumbersome
                }{}
                \noexpand\stepcounter{counter}
            }
        }\temp
    }
Temp Value:\tempVariable
\end{document}

So can anyone explain me, what is the correct way how to achieve this in the smartest way?

what's the second approach? you have a 'first' and 'third' in your code comments, but your question is about the 'second'.

Every foreach step is inside a group, so just save it globally by using \xdef or possibly \global\let\foo=\foo.

still using ifthen and foreach instead if the much more poweful and consistent expl3 loops? Really you shouldn't use ifthn package for programmatic code (check the author of that package)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/726578/how-to-check-expl3-function-return-value-with-ifthenelse#comment1808663_726578

You should first state precisely the problem and the expected result; your attempts might be useful to see, but the full specifications are more important. To be honest, I can't understand what the target is.

@cfr Sorry my fault, this was a relic when I tried different approaches. I corrected it!

@DavidCarlisle Yes you are right, I got that point from the last question. But I have about 2k lines of "legacy" code. And I can not rework everything with my level of knowledge within days or weeks... All my questions are based on the same root document, my smart home electric plan. And unfortunately in a few weeks, I need this documentation to build up my house ;)

@egreg Okay, I gave my best to summarize it. The problem is, that I need to store the variable \tempVariable within my nested \foreach-loop. That's what I meant with "Sometimes I need to temporarily store some of these parameters. For this Use-Case I would like to find the best approach." When you compile the code as it is, the expected result is already there, but the approach seems not to be the right way (to call a function just to store the variable). But probably DavidCarlisle already answered this question in the comment when he told me, that I should use LaTeX3 syntax...

@JohnKormylo wow, \xdef (eXpanded Define) did the job! I never heard about that. I just knew \gdef or \def. Thanks a lot!

I’m voting to close this question because the issue seems to be fixed in comments.

The correct hint was given by John Kormylo in the comments above! Within the nested \foreach loop I need to use \xdef (eXpanded Define) instead of \edef to set my \tempVariable!
Here is the working MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcounter{counter}
\newcommand{\tempVariable}{}
\newcommand{\firstInnerElement}{value1}
\newcommand{\secondInnerElement}{value2}
\newcommand{\thirdInnerElement}{value3}

\def\innerArray{
    {\firstInnerElement},{\secondInnerElement},{\thirdInnerElement}
}

\def\outerArray{
    {\innerArray}
}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{counter}{1}
    \foreach \elementA in \outerArray {
        \begingroup
        \edef\temp{\endgroup
            \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\elementB in \elementA {
                \noexpand\ifthenelse{\noexpand\equal{\noexpand\the\value{counter}}{2}}{
                     \noexpand\xdef\noexpand\tempVariable{value2}
                }{}
                \noexpand\stepcounter{counter}
            }
        }\temp
    }
Temp Value:\tempVariable
\end{document}

